# Difficulties with solving the exercises in the K Framework Tutorial

Tags: kframework

**Tutorial 1 Lesson 8  ( mu-defined )**

My attempt is to substitute the  existing rule : "rule mu X . E => E[(mu X . E) / X]"

with the rule :

```
    rule mu X:KVar . E:Exp
    => let X =
    (lambda $x . (( lambda X . E) (lambda $y . ($x $x $y))))
    (lambda $x . (( lambda X . E) (lambda $y . ($x $x $y))))    [macro]"
```

Unfortanetely it wont compile. What am i doing wrong ? Is this solution correct ?

**Tutorial 1 Lesson 8 ( SK-combinators )**

They have this part in the README of the exercise:

" For example, `lambda x . if x then y else z` cannot be transformed into combinators as is,
but it can if we assume a builtin conditional function constant, say `cond`,
and desugar `if_then_else_` to it.  Then this expression becomes
`lambda x . (((cond x) y) z)`, which we know how to transform. "

My struggle is with ' say `cond`, and desugar `if_then_else_` to it. '

How do i do this part ? Any help would be appreciated.

**Tutorial 2 Lesson 4 (purely-syntactic)**

They have this part in the README of the exercise:

'Hint: make sequential composition `strict(1)` or `seqstrict`, and have
statements reduce to `{}` instead of `.`; and don't forget to make
`{}` a `KResult` (you may need a new syntactic category for that, which
only includes `{}` and is included in `KResult`).'

My struggle is with the part: ' and have
statements reduce to `{}` instead of `.`; and don't forget to make
`{}` a `KResult` (you may need a new syntactic category for that, which
only includes `{}` and is included in `KResult`)'

How do i do this ? Any hints ?

**Tutorial 2 Lesson 4 (uninitialized-variables)**

I have created the following module:

```
module UNDEFINED

    rule <k> int (X,Xs => Xs);_ </k> <state> Rho:Map (.Map => X|->"##") </state>
    requires notBool (X in keys(Rho))

endmodule
```

But this initializes variables with "##". How do i initialize a variable with "undefined" ? Any hints ?

**Tutorial 3 Lesson 1 (callCC)**

For this exercise i created a very similar code similar to the callcc:

```
    syntax Exp ::= "callCC" Exp  [strict]
    syntax Val ::= cc(K)
    rule <k> (callCC V:Val => V cc(K)) ~> _ </k>
    rule <k> cc(K) V ~> _ =>  V ~> _ </k>
```

For some reason it wont compile . What am i doing wrong ? Is this solution correct ?

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, giving you answers to these would be giving you answers to the exercises in the tutorial. As these are intended to be homework assignments for a course, we'd rather not have the answers publicly available online.

Comment: If you've got more specific questions about technical difficulties, we'd be happy to help you out!

Comment: Hints would be helpfull @nishantjr.